# Regex for %{ ... %} comment

Tags: java, regex, matlab, comments

I am trying to filter out using Java regex from a Matlab source code all multiple line comments of the form: **%{ (anything here) %}**.

My test file is the following:

```
a = magic(3);
%{
sum(a)
diag(a)
sum(diag(a))
%}
sum(diag(fliplr(a)))
```

My pattern is the following:

```
%\\{.*%\\}\n
```

However, when replacing with empty string all occurrences of this pattern in the text (with the method replaceAll), the multiple line comment is not removed. Why isn't my pattern good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable DOTALL mode `(?s)` so that the dot in your regex would also match the line breaks . And also you must need to make `.*` as non-greedy.

```
"(?s)%\\{.*?%\\}\n?"
```

Code:

```
String inputString = "a = magic(3);\n" + 
        "%{\n" + 
        "sum(a)\n" + 
        "diag(a)\n" + 
        "sum(diag(a))\n" + 
        "%}\n" + 
        "sum(diag(fliplr(a)))";
System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll("(?s)%\\{.*?%\\}\n?", ""));
```

Output:

```
a = magic(3);
sum(diag(fliplr(a)))
```

Comment: @Eszter turn the `\n` at the last in the above regex as optional. See my update. If it still won't work then post the exact input in your question.

Comment: The funny thing is, if I code the text into a String just as you did, it works perfectly fine, but if I try it with my text, it doesn't work...I copy-pasted the content of the file I read and then try to format to my question...

Comment: yep, that's why i suggest you to turn last `\n` as optional by adding `?` next to the `\n` ...